# pg_start_backup vs pg_basebackup

Tags: postgresql, backup, postgresql-12

I read stuff about `pg_start_backup` from [here](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/exclusive-backup-deprecated-what-now/) and `pg_base_backup` [here](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/what-does-pg_start_backup-do/).

I got confused. So, out of the 2 methods, **which one is generally better** ?
Seems that `pg_start_backup` is better than `pg_base_backup`. But, `pg_base_backup` has parameter to be the same as `pg_start_backup` with `pg_basebackup –xlog-method=stream` command.

If I have a situation like this :

- no clustering
- logical replication of some tables (not the whole database)
- no hot standby
- 1 db physical server with many databases in one instance
- want to implement PITR

Which one is suitable for me ? I am just confused.

Postgres 12.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking this question, `pg_basebackup` is what you should use. `pg_start_backup()` (or `pg_backup_start()` from v15 on) is the low-level, much more complicated way of doing the same thing, which can give you more flexibility if you need that.